# Does the formula p(X|(Y,Z)=(y,z)) =p((X|Y=y)|(Z|Y=y)=z) hold?

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose we have three absolutely continuous random vectors $X, Y, Z$ with joint normal distribution. I want to prove that

$$p(X|(Y,Z)=(y,z)) =p((X|Y=y)|(Z|Y=y)=z)$$
Put differently $p(X|(Y,Z)=(y,z))=p(\hat{X}(y)|\hat{Z}(y))$, where $\hat{X}(y)=(X|Y=y)$ and $\hat{Z}(y)=(Z|Y=y)$.

**Example of use**
This theorem is usually used to derive Kalman filter without even writing it down.

E.g. Anderson, B. D. O., Moore, J. B.: Optimal filtering. Prentice-Hall 1979.

**Update**
Sorry for changing the theorem completely, but I have finally figured it out and realized that I was really inaccurate... Steps are to realize that they are both normal and then to compute means and variances and show that they are equal. I would still be grateful if someone could prove/disprove the statement only with assumption that X, Y, Z are normal but not jointly normal.

I have found exactly the same type of derivation that I wanted to make on slides here: http://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/kf.pdf - slides 14, 15 where this problem is stated as obvious.

Comment: How do you define $p((X\mid Y)\mid(Z\mid Y))$?

Comment: You can imagine $X|Y$ as a new variable, let´s say $\hat{X}$ and the same for $Z|Y$ as $\hat{Z}$.Then you have $p((X|Y)|(Z|Y))=p(\hat{X}|\hat{Z})=\frac{p(\hat{X},\hat{Z})}{p(\hat{Z})}=‌​p((X|Y),(Z|Y))/p(Z|Y)$. Now you could further extend $p(Z|Y)$ but I think that this will not help.

Comment: The meaning of 'imagining $X\mid Y$ as a new variable' is unclear.

Comment: There is no such thing as $X\mid Y$, only $P(X\in A\mid Y)$ is a well-defined object.

Comment: The question underwent so many modifications that answers below may have become partly irrelevant. The latter is a strong indication that the former should be avoided (but the OP knows better...).

Answer (score 4):

First, the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and the conditional distribution of $Z$ conditionally on $Y$ cannot determine the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $(Y,Z)$.

*Counterexample:* Assume first that $(X,Y,Z)$ is i.i.d. standard normal, then the conditional distributions of $X$ conditionally on $Y$, of $Z$ conditionally on $Y$ and of $X$ conditionally on $(Y,Z)$ are standard normal. Now, assume that $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. standard normal and that $X=Z$, then the conditional distributions of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and of $Z$ conditionally on $Y$ are standard normal yet the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $(Y,Z)$ is the Dirac measure at $Z$.

An exercise which can help understand the situation is to compare this counterexample with your "example of use" and to spot the exact place where the former destroys the latter.

Second, there is no such thing as conditional *random variables* $\hat X=X\mid Y$ or $\hat Z=Z\mid Y$ hence, for example, the expression
$$
\hat X\mid \hat Z
$$
is simply undefined. All one has to work with are conditional *distributions*.

Comment: I do not agree with your counterexample. I am persuaded that we end up with Dirac measure in both cases. In my example we would have $\hat{X}=\hat{Z}$ and therefore $\Sigma_{xz}=\Sigma_x=\Sigma_z$. Secondly, I do agree with your comment about variable $\hat{X}=X|Y$, I should write $\hat{X}(y)=X|Y=y$ and therefore $\mu_x$ should be $\mu_x(y)$ and so on...

Comment: You think that if (X,Y,Z) is i.i.d. standard normal then the conditional distribution of X conditionally on (Y,Z) is Dirac? Well... what can I say? :-)

Comment: No, I do not think so. But you wrote it as to examples: 1) (X,Y,Z) iid. -> both cases normal, as you state and I do agree. 2) (X,Y,X) -> you state and I do agree X|(Y,X) Dirac and (X|Y)|(X|Y) you state normal, I say Dirac.

Comment: "No, I do not think so." But you wrote exactly that. "2) (X,Y,X) -> you state and I do agree X|(Y,X) Dirac and (X|Y)|(X|Y) you state normal, I say Dirac." **Whaaat?** Could you please indicate where I would have used the notion or the notation (X|Y)|(X|Y)? Since I never have, where did I "state normal" (your words)? Since I nowhere did so, what are you talking about? For some accurate and precise statements destroying any hope that the notation (X|Y)|(Z|Y) could be anything but a meaningless string of characters, please see my post. Oh and just in case: *read slowly*.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used your words I just use more convenient notation, so your words are: "Now, assume that (X,Y) is i.i.d. standard normal and that X=Z, then the conditional distributions of X conditionally on Y and of Z conditionally on Y are standard normal". If you do not mean the same in that sentence as I with the notation (X|Y)|(X|Y), where (X,Y) are iid. Then I do not see why you call it a counterexample...

Comment: It is a counterexample because it is another case where  the conditional distributions of X conditionally on Y and of Z conditionally on Y are the same as in the other case, and yet the conditional distribution of X conditionally on (Y,Z) is different (Dirac instead of standard normal). These two examples together prove that the conditional distributions of X conditionally on Y and of Z conditionally on Y do not determine the conditional distribution of X conditionally on (Y,Z). This, as everything else I wrote, does not use the notation (X|Y)|(Z|Y) (which, as already said, is a monstrosity).

Answer (score 0):

How about a counter-example?

Suppose we have the 8 states and there probabilities as follow:

[image]

In this case, P(X) is just 0.5.  But P(Z|Y) = 0.01

P(X|Y,Z) = 0.5 (probability of state 1 divided by probability of states 1 and 2)

P(X|Y) x P(Z|Y) = 0.5 x 0.01 = 0.05, much less than the 0.5 of P(X|Y,Z)

Comment: I don't see how this is an counterexample, as the question does not claim anything about the product of $P(X\mid Y)$ and $P(Z\mid Y)$. (Although, it is unclear to me what the claim in the question is).

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes, this is really something else than I wanted... But I will put an example which I actually need it for for better understanging